# How to go to a previous commit without deleting recent commits

Tags: git, github

Assume that I have made following commits: c1, c2, c3 and that I am presently on commit c3. Now I want to go back to commit c1 without removing c2 and c3 commits. Once I am on c1, I want to create another branch from there. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the branch directly:

`git branch newbranch commitid`

And `commitid` can be a lot of things. `HEAD~2` will do what you want for your specific example.

And by the way, you wouldn't even lose c2 and c3 if you just checked out c1: they are available in the reflog (see `git reflog`).

Comment: Thanks for replying. So if I have to goto c2, I use commitid as HEAD~1 ? Ans yes, I also have to checkout on newbranch.

Comment: You can even checkout directly if you want, just replace `branch` with `checkout -b` in the command above. And yes, that would be `HEAD~1`. In git parlance, in fact, it is not a commitid but a refspec, which can be so many things it's not even funny.

Comment: What if I just want to goto C1 but this time I donot want to branch from c1 ?

Comment: Then just `git checkout` it. Git will warn you that you are currently not on a branch, but it can be done. And if you want to create a branch from this point, use `git branch newbranch HEAD`.